# Updating value at address stored in register in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I have an character array initialized under `.data` as follows:

```
array: .byte '-':42
```

Say I load the address of the array into `$t0`:

```
la $t0, array
```

I want to change the character stored at the address in `$t0` to the character 'X', but I'm having trouble accomplishing this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "Store Immediate" command on MIPS.

To write "X" into a character array, assign [the ASCII code for "X"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) to a general purpose register, then store that register's lower byte into the array at $t0 with a SB (Store Byte) command.

```
li $t1, 0x58
sb $t1, ($t0)
```

`li` (Load Immediate) is not a *bona fide* MIPS instruction, it's pseudoinstruction, similar to an assembler macro. Internally, it's translated into

```
addi $t1, $0, 0x58
```

Not all assemblers support pseudoinstructions.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am getting a syntax error using the first line you have there. For the record, I am using QtSpim.

Comment: I would be careful about using the word macro when you mean pseudo-instruction. Macros are [something different](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/MacrosHelp.html)

Comment: The line is thin. Specifically `li` can become either one command or two, depending on the constant value. Some texts call those "built-in macros".